# Download mp3 file from android browser

Tags: php, android-browser

I referred to these questions and implemented their answers but none of them is working for me.

[download mp3 instead of playing in browser by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499773/download-mp3-instead-of-playing-in-browser-by-default)

[PHP Streaming MP3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358253/php-streaming-mp3)

[content type for mp3 download response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017694/content-type-for-mp3-download-response)

[download mp3 from web url with android failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802789/download-mp3-from-web-url-with-android-failed)

Basically when the user clicks a download link on the website, we want the user to be prompted to download the audio file.

**Code :**

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: $mtype");         
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name);
readfile($fname);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . $fsize);
```

Here, `$mtype` is `"audio/mpeg"`

**Success :**

1. It's working fine on all desktop browsers.
2. I tried with a BlackBerry, and I got the downloaded file.

**Failure :**

1. when i do same with android browsers, I did't get the downloaded file.
2. file name also missing, comes with `<untitled>` and shows the status `"download unsuccessful"`.

Thank you if you have any idea why this code doesn't work on an Android phone.

Comment: For start, try sending headers before you perform `readfile`.

Comment: @N.B., i try this also but no more success.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem and it could be that ur server does not allow you to use mp3 files properly ( I use Biz.nf )

Answer (score 0):

I have just found solution of this problem. On my android Xiaomi it works perfectly.

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    echo "OK";
    if (ob_get_level()) {
  ob_end_clean();
} // clearing output script buffer

$mime_type = "audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3";
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: {$mime_type}');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```